# How can I bind an array of objects to arcs in a D3 pie chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a pie chart and my data is in the form of a JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Stage":"birth",
    "Avg":19071
  },
 { 
   //
 }
]
```

I don't know how I should use the data function to bind that json data to my selection. So this is not working for me:

```
pie = d3.layout.pie();

arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc") 
  .data(pie(data)) // ?
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr({
    "transform" : "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")",
    "class": function(d,i){
      console.log(d3.keys(d));
    }       
  });

pie.sort(null);

//Draw arc paths  
arcs.append("path")
  .attr({
    "d": arc,
    "class" : "arc"
  });
```

How do I use .data so I can have access to each key/value pair in the json? Sorry if this is a really simple question but I can't wrap my head around how keys work in this case.

Comment: means previously you hava data like [1970, 1971...]..like that now you have [{xxx: 1970, xxx: 'sdafsdf'}, { ......}]...right ?

Comment: @saikumar yes it's like [{xxx: 1970, xxx: 'sdafsdf'}, { ......}]. I'm used to working with flat arrays in D3. I will edit my wording for clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your `layout.pie` a [value accessor](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#value) function.

```
var pie = d3.layout
  .pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d){
    return d.Avg; //<-- d3 will pie the values in Avg property
   });
```

---

Full working sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      "Stage": "birth",
      "Avg": 19071
    }, {
      "Stage": "death",
      "Avg": 10000
    }];
    
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);
      
    var colors = d3.scale.category10();

    var pie = d3.layout
      .pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.Avg;
      })

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(90)
      .innerRadius(0);

    var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
      .data(pie(data)) //<-- this is fine
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr({
        "transform": "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")",
        "class": function(d, i) {
          return d.data.Stage; //<-- after pieing the data, the raw data is then in the data property
        }
      });

    //Draw arc paths  
    arcs.append("path")
      .attr({
        "d": arc,
        "class": "arc"
      })
      .style('fill', function(d,i){
        return colors(i);
      })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```